# How to create a new file inside vs code using browser protocols

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a new file using browser protocols However, I don't know the name of the protocol and can't find any docs.

for example
`vscode:new-file://snippet.txt`

Comment: I don't think creating a file like this is possible.

Comment: @Charlie, Do you know the name of the protocol? I might be able to research it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code does not offer creation of files via the browser protocol as of version 1.58. However it allows opening of files and folders using this method.

`vscode://file/{full path}/`

Example -

vscode://file/c:/myProject/package.json

Note that you can use these urls directly in Windows Explorer too.

Documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line#_opening-vs-code-with-urls